# Collect all the Keys from a HashMap associated with the Lowest into a List

Tags: java, java-stream

How to sort HashMap entries by Value and print all the Keys mapped the Lowest Value

Here is my `HashMap`.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("John", 1);
map.put("Matthew", 12);
map.put("Clara", 53);
map.put("Keith", 2);
```

*Expected output:*

```
John
```

I am trying to sort them, so I can get "John" to be collected in the list.

```
List<String> keys = res.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue())
    .limit(1)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now, let's consider another map.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("John", 2);
map.put("Matthew", 12);
map.put("Clara", 53);
map.put("Keith", 2);
```

*Expected output:*

```
John, Keith
```

How can I get both `John` and `Keith` to be added to the list in case of a tie (*i.e. both associated with the lowest value*) ?

Comment: Why did you write the `map` twice and for `John` and `Keith` with `2`. Is it a typo?

Comment: Firstly, you can't sort a hashmap (ie change the order of its entries), but you can *sort* its entries if you copy them to a List. What do you mean "in case of a tie print them all"? Do you mean only print all entries if multiple entries have the same value? Something else? Please add expected output to your question.

Comment: @Bohemian yes, I want to sort the entries and copy them over to a list.

Comment: `int min = Collections.min(map.values()); List<String> keys = map.entrySet() .stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() == min).map(Map.Entry::getKey).toList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the entries into a `Map<Integer, List<Map.Entry>>` grouping by their values, get the entries that correspond to the minimum value, then convert those entries to a list of their keys:

```java
List<String> lowestValuedNames = map.entrySet().stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue))
  .get(Collections.min(map.values()))
  .stream()
  .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/j3I8Tc).

Not particularly efficient, but done using one line.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done **without sorting**, as well as without creating an **intermediate map** (and performing an additional iteration over its entries to find the entry with the lowest key). I.e. we can do better in terms of both memory allocation and performance.

For that, we need to maintain a collection of entries having the lowest value encountered so far and compare the value of every encountered entry with the value of the first element in the collection. If the collection is empty or if values are the same, we need to add the next entry. If the value of the next entry is lower, we need to clear the collection and then add the entry. And the value of the next entry is greater than we should ignore it.

To implement this approach with streams, we can create a *custom collector* using static method `Collector.of()`.

That's how it can be implemented:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> people = 
        Map.of("John", 2, "Matthew", 12,
               "Clara", 53, "Keith", 2);

    List<String> result = people.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collector.of(
            ArrayDeque::new,
            (Deque<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> deque, Map.Entry<String, Integer> next) -> {
                if (!deque.isEmpty() && deque.peek().getValue() > next.getValue()) deque.clear();
                if (deque.isEmpty() || deque.peek().getValue().equals(next.getValue())) deque.add(next);
            },
            (left, right) -> {
                if (left.isEmpty()) return right;
                if (right.isEmpty()) return left;
                if (left.peek().getValue() < right.peek().getValue()) return left;
                if (left.peek().getValue() > right.peek().getValue()) return right;
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            },
            deque -> deque.stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList())
        ));

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The *collector* is still performing the final iteration over the resulting collection of entries to extract the *keys*. We can omit this step and simplify the code by encapsulating the logic that currently resides in the *collector* into a separate class. And the instance of that class would be used by the *collector* as a *mutable container* instead of a collection and will be responsible for doing all the housekeeping.

```
class EntryContainer implements Consumer<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> {
    private int value;
    private List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Override
    public void accept(Map.Entry<String, Integer> next) {
        if (!names.isEmpty() && next.getValue() < value) names.clear();
        if (names.isEmpty() || value == next.getValue()) {
            names.add(next.getKey());
            value = next.getValue();
        }
    }
    
    public EntryContainer merge(EntryContainer other) {
        if (names.isEmpty() || !other.names.isEmpty() && other.value < value) return other;
        if (other.names.isEmpty() || value < other.value) return this;
        names.addAll(other.names);
        return this;
    }
    
    public List<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }
}
```

Now we can apply it. The collector no longer looks intimidating, and we don't need a finisher function, instead the collection of names is being handed out by the collector's container at the end of the stream execution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> people =
        Map.of("John", 2, "Matthew", 12,
               "Clara", 53, "Keith", 2);
    
    List<String> result = people.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collector.of(
            EntryContainer::new,
            EntryContainer::accept,
            EntryContainer::merge
        ))
        .getNames();
    
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

*Output:*

```
[Keith, John]
```